# Can I provide macro/reference as parameter for hierarchical access in testbench? (SystemVerilog)

Tags: system-verilog

I have some modules that I want to print some wires from in a `PRINTER` module. I have two different testbenches, which wraps these modules slightly differently, see code below. Is it possible to use the same `PRINTER` to print `print_me_a` and `print_me_b` using hierarchical references?

I know all the hierarchical references in the testbenches, and I know I could expand the `PRINTER` to instead take inputs and then connect relative references there, but hierarchical references inside the `PRINTER` are easier to expand if I want to add a lot of new prints, then I only have to change in the `PRINTER`.

Given the structure below I can't really utilize `bind` to make it work in both testbenches. I tried to instead of instance references use `MOD_A.print_me_a` and `MOD_B.print_me_b`, and that worked when I use `VCS`, but not in `Questa`, and I would like for the solution to work in both.

Is there any way to provide an hierarchical reference or name, or some macro, to the `PRINTER` as a parameter maybe, so that I can have the same code inside `PRINTER` for printing the wires in both testbenches? Or can I utilize some parameter which tells me which testbench the instance is used in to `generate` some different macros like  `` `define MOD_A_DEF known_name_wrap_a.known_name_a `` for later common usage in `PRINTER`?

```
module MOD_A();
   wire print_me_a; // I want to print this
endmodule

module WRAP_A();
   MOD_A known_name_a();
endmodule

module MOD_B();
   wire print_me_b; // I want to print this
endmodule

module TOP_MOD();
   WRAP_A known_name_wrap_a();
   MOD_B known_name_b();
endmodule
```

```
module PRINTER();
   // Pseudo code, can I access these with hierarchical ref?
   $display(known_name_wrap_a.known_name_a.print_me_a)   // Only works in TOP_TB
   $display(known_name_a.print_me_a)                     // Only works in OTHER_TB
   $display(known_name_b.print_me_b);                    // Happens to work fine in both
endmodule
```

```
module TOP_TB();
   TOP_MOD top_mod();

   bind top_mod
   PRINTER top_tb_printer();
endmodule
```

```
module OTHER_TB();
   MOD_A known_name_a();
   MOD_B known_name_b();

   PRINTER other_tb_printer();
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use ports in your PRINTER module and connect them with relative hierarchical references.

```
module PRINTER(input wire a,b);
   initial $display(a);
   initial $display(b);
endmodule

module TOP_TB();
   TOP_MOD top_mod();

   bind top_mod PRINTER top_tb_printer(
       known_name_wrap_a.known_name_a.print_me_a,
       known_name_b.print_me_b
       );
endmodule

module OTHER_TB();
   MOD_A known_name_a();
   MOD_B known_name_b();

   PRINTER other_tb_printer(
       known_name_a.print_me_a
       known_name_b.print_me_b);
endmodule
```

Comment: Thanks, and yes I know that I could use inputs connected with references, I might not have been clear enough about that in the description, but I was wondering if that was the only way or if I could do it in some other way utilizing parameters, macros or something similar. But my guess then is that that is not possible?